# Need a specific range in the Publishobject for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get a specific range to be published like `$A$1:$O$$25` instead of `xlSourceSheet`

```
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add("$A$1:$O$$25", _
                 x, Sname, , _
                 xlHtmlStatic, , "")
                 Range("A1").Activate
                 .Publish (True)
                 .AutoRepublish = False '~~> True updates HTML when workbook is saved
End With
```

The above is throwing an error. here x and Sname are variable defined at the starting my main aim to publish certain part of the sheet only.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for the above posting here which may help others.

> 

```
 Dim objRange As Range   Dim objcoord As String  
          Set objRange =ActiveSheet.Range("A1:P25")
    >             objcoord = objRange.Address
    >             With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
    >                     x, Sname, _
    >                     objcoord, _
    >                     xlHtmlStatic, , "")
    >                     Range("A1").Activate
    >                     .Publish (True)
    >                     .AutoRepublish = False '~~> True updates HTML when workbook is saved
    >             End With
```